# Availity 270 Eligibility Request always return AAA*N**79*C~ error

Tags: edi, x12

I am trying to test 270 Eligibility Request for BCBS Texas through Availity but it always returns **AAA*N**79*C~** error after NM*PR line. I am really new to this and have no idea what could be wrong with the 270 request. I tried to search AAA error and it seems that PayerID in NM1 line is not identified by Availity and maybe incorrect but I tried different insurance companies(Aetna FL and United Healthcare Oxford Navigate) and they are also returned with same error at exact same line(they have different PayerID in their 270 file).
Any help would be appreciated on this issue, I know I am messing up something in 270 request for sure but don't know exactly what is messed up.

```
270 Request:
ISA*00*          *00*          *ZZ*AV09311993     *01*123456789      *200110*0818*^*00501*000000193*1*P*:~
GS*HS*AV01101957*123456789*20200110*0818*000000193*X*005010X279A1~
ST*270*0001*005010X279A1~
BHT*0022*13*244579*20200110*0818~
HL*1**20*1~
NM1*PR*2*BCBSTX*****PI*84980~
HL*2*1*21*1~
NM1*1P*2*Provider Name*****SV*1234567890~
NM1*40*2*AVAIL*****46*030240928~
HL*3*2*22*0~
TRN*1*00012*1234567890~
NM1*IL*1******MI*ABC1234567~
DTP*291*RD8*20100101-20200110~
EQ*30~
SE*13*0001~
GE*1*000000193~
IEA*1*000000193~


271 Response:
ISA*00*          *00*          *01*123456789      *ZZ*AV09311993     *200112*0816*^*00501*220190332*0*P*:~
GS*HB*123456789*AV01101957*20200112*0816*123456789*X*005010X279A1~
ST*271*1001*005010X279A1~
BHT*0022*11*244579*20200110*0818~
HL*1**20*1~
NM1*PR*2*BCBSTX*****PI*84980~
AAA*N**79*C~
HL*2*1*21*1~
NM1*1P*2*Provider Name*****SV*1234567890~
HL*3*2*22*0~
TRN*2*00012*1234567890~
NM1*IL*1******MI*ABC1234567~
DTP*291*RD8*20100101-20200110~
EB*V~
SE*13*1001~
GE*1*123456789~
IEA*1*220190332~
```

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are using an incorrect payer ID. Try using the following:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

79 Invalid Participant Identification
Description: Use this code to indicate that the value in either GS02 or GS03 is invalid.